# How can I get the PointIndices of a given PointCloud?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

For example:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr example_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);

//cloud is populated

pcl::PointIndices::Ptr point_indices(new pcl::PointIndices);
```

How do I populate point_indices with the indices of example_cloud?

Comment: What is your reason to want this?

Comment: I want to subtract two clouds as described here: http://www.pcl-users.org/Subtracting-clouds-td3569049.html#a3569868

Comment: I'd +1 the message from Nicola Fioraio in the referenced thread.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using RANSAC with PCL, and the object `pcl::RandomSampleConsensus` has the method `getInliers(vector<int>&)`, and with this method, I got the indices of the result after applying RANSAC. The vector of `getInliers(vector<int>&)` can be assigned to your `point_indices`. In the end, I needed a method, as you answered in a comment, for the subtraction of a point cloud from another. The code for the subtraction of point clouds is next:

```
void subtract_points(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud, const vector<int>& inliers)
{
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr fInliers (new pcl::PointIndices);

  fInliers->indices = inliers;

  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
  extract.setInputCloud (cloud);
  extract.setIndices (fInliers);
  extract.setNegative(true);
  extract.filter(*cloud);
}
```

The concrete code for obtain the vector of indices is (with RANSAC):

```
vector<int> inliers;
// Plane model
pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr model_p (new pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud));

pcl::RandomSampleConsensus<pcl::PointXYZ> ransac (model_p);
ransac.getInliers(inliers);
```

As you can see, later we can define a `PointIndice` object and assign our vector of indices directly: `point_indices->indices = my_indices`

I hope it helps someone looking for the same (the code for the subtraction of point clouds works).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer with pcl::ExtractIndices works great, but I just want to add the possibilities of using [pcl::copyPointCloud (const pcl::PointCloud< PointT > &cloud_in, const std::vector< pcl::PointIndices > &indices, pcl::PointCloud< PointT > &cloud_out)](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/group__common.html#gac6598b085fc7e60e0283f83892001197)

So that you can use it like this

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr example_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr extracted_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr point_indices(new pcl::PointIndices); 

pcl::copyPointCloud(*example_cloud, *point_indices, *extracted_cloud);
```

Also, if you are looking for the difference, you can try to use [c++ set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference). PointIndices::indices is essentially a [std::vector](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/structpcl_1_1_point_indices.html#aa74aac0d2901a2b003f5ef3213dd1baa) so you can follow the c++ tutorial link to do the difference.